# Не запускается функция closeEvent(), PyQt

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, closeevent

Прописал метод `closeEvent()` в классе, но он не работает. Второй день ломаю голову, сайт уже перечитал.

Метод `closeEvent()` уже везде где только можно наставил.
Хочу, чтобы в этом методе сохранялись переменные перед закрытием можно и без вывода диалогового окна.

Часть кода урезал лишние формулы и элементы.

**temp.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 560)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 560))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 681, 541))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 0))
        # *************
        self.lock_btn.setObjectName("lock_btn")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lock_btn)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "88:88:88 8888 88-88-8888"))
        self.home_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Home"))
  *****************************
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Переменные программы"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Название Программы"))
        self.settings_titleProgram.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "88"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Описание"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Описание"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**New_main.py**:

```
import sys
import configparser
from builtins import print

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QLabel,QDialog
from temp import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer,QDateTime


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Start program')

        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('file.ini')

        #print (config['DEFAULT']['settings_titleProgram'] )

        self.main_win = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)

        self.timer=QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        self.showHome()

        text1 =self.ui.settings_titleProgram.text()
        print(text1)
        self.main_win.setWindowTitle(text1)
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.home)

        self.ui.home_btn.clicked.connect(self.showHome)
        self.ui.lock_btn.clicked.connect(self.showLock)
        self.ui.settings_btn.clicked.connect(self.showSettings)
        # *******************************

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('close')

    def showHome(self):
        self.main_win.show()
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.home)
        print('home')

    def showSettings(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.settings)
        print('settings')

    # *****************

    def save_ini(self):
        print('Сохраняем')
        text1 =self.ui.settings_titleProgram.text()
        print(text1)

        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('file.ini')
        config['DEFAULT']['settings_titleProgram'] = 999
        with open('file.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)

    # Вывод времени
    def startTimer(self):
        self.timer.start(500)
        #self.startBtn.setEnabled(False)
        #self.endBtn.setEnabled(True)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time=QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        formatted_time=current_time.toString('hh:mm:ss dddd dd-MM-yyyy')
        self.ui.label_2.setText(formatted_time)

def closeEvent(self, event):
    print('close')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ну так свой класс надо унаследовать от `QMainWindow` или `QWigdet`, чтобы событийный функционал работал.

Comment: Сейчас попробую переписать класс, чтобы функционал работал

Comment: @user207200  слово ИЛИ тут не подходит. Наследовать надо от виджета, в котором создавалась форма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что вы предоставили никак не воспроизводится и проверить ваш код не возможно.

Но похоже на то, что вы как-то странно пишите класс основного окна приложения.
Обычно это делается так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
...

# так:
# from temp import Ui_MainWindow
# или так:
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
...


# -------------> vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvv <------------------------------# !!! +++
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                              #
    def __init__(self):                                                    #
        super().__init__()                                                 # +++
        self.setupUi(self)
...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
    
        # сохраняте все что вам надо перед закрытием приложения
        # или вызовите другой метод, например self.save_ini()
        # где вы хотите эти сохранения сделать
        print('close')

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        formatted_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm:ss dddd dd-MM-yyyy')
# !!!   vvvvvvvvvvvv вот так вы обращаетесь к объектам, которые указаны в форме <----
        self.label_2.setText(formatted_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()                                                               # !!! +++ 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Я удалил все, что мешало запустить ваше приложение, чтобы убедиться, что метод `closeEvent()` работает.

```
import sys
import configparser
from builtins import print
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, \
    QLabel, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QDateTime


#from temp import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 560)
#        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 560))
#        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 192, 225);")
# ?        
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 681, 541))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.layoutWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(192, 192, 225);")
        
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)   #(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
#        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(350, 0))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(192, 192, 0);")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        
#        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
# *************
#        self.lock_btn = 
#        self.horizontalLayout =
#        self.lock_btn.setObjectName("lock_btn")
#        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lock_btn)
#        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
# ?        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "88:88:88 8888 88-88-8888"))
#        self.home_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Home"))
#  *****************************
#        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Переменные программы"))
#        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Название Программы"))
#        self.settings_titleProgram.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "88"))
#        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Описание"))
#        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
#        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Описание"))
        
# -------------> vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvvvvvvvvv <------------------------------# !!! +++
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                              #
    def __init__(self):                                                    #
        super().__init__()                                                 # +++
        self.setupUi(self)                                                 # +++

        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('file.ini')

# ?      self.main_win = QMainWindow()
# ?      self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
# ?      self.ui.setupUi(self.main_win)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        self.timer.start(1000)

# ?      self.showHome()
#                    #
#        text1 =self.ui.settings_titleProgram.text()
        text1 = '1'                             # self.settings_titleProgram.text()
        print(text1)
        
#        self.main_win.setWindowTitle(text1)
        self.setWindowTitle(text1)
        self.home = 0
#        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.home)

#        self.home_btn.clicked.connect(self.showHome)
#        self.lock_btn.clicked.connect(self.showLock)
#        self.settings_btn.clicked.connect(self.showSettings)
        # *******************************


    def closeEvent(self, event):
    
        # сохраняте все что вам надо перед закрытием приложения
        # или вызовите другой метод, например self.save_ini()
        # где вы хотите эти сохранения сделать
        print('close')

# ?    def showHome(self):
# ?        self.main_win.show()
# ?        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.home)
# ?        print('home')

    def showSettings(self):
#        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.settings)
        print('settings')

    # *****************

    def save_ini(self):
        print('Сохраняем')
        text1 =self.settings_titleProgram.text()
        print(text1)

        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('file.ini')
        config['DEFAULT']['settings_titleProgram'] = 999
        with open('file.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)

# Вывод времени # ??? ?# ??? ?# ??? ?# ??? ?# ??? ?
# ?    def startTimer(self):
# ?        self.timer.start(500)
# ?        #self.startBtn.setEnabled(False)
# ?        #self.endBtn.setEnabled(True)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        formatted_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm:ss dddd dd-MM-yyyy')
# !!!   vvvvvvvvvvvv вот так вы обращаетесь к объектам, которые указаны в форме <----
        self.label_2.setText(formatted_time)

# ---> что это # ?
# def closeEvent(self, event):
#     print('close')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()                                                               # !!! +++ 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас буду пробовать)))

Comment: @НиколайIntendant удачи, напишите что у вас получилось.

Comment: Сразу скажу -заработало!!! Спасибо Вам! Я в этом ...

Comment: @НиколайIntendant пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Деле новичок, нашел в интернете код который меня устроил, но столкнулся с такими на первый взгляд проблемами.

Comment: Я весь функционал программы начал переносить и он работает! Он работает, Благодарю Вам за откорректированный код! Обязательно поставлю правильный.